# Deployement server Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, web, jboss5.x

When I try to run my server I received this problem :

```
Deployment "vfsfile:/C:/Users/aroua/jbdevstudioo/jboss-eap/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/ProjetNew.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/Users/aroua/jbdevstudioo/jboss-eap/jboss-as/server/default/tmp/aa02f-eoixe9-h0nnnr10-1-h0nnofam-v/ProjetNew.war/ deployment failed

11:23:29,691 INFO [Http11Protocol] D?marrage de Coyote HTTP/1.1 sur http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080
11:23:29,719 INFO [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009
11:23:29,727 INFO [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.0.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_0_0_GA date=200910202128)] Started in 2m:39s:918ms
```

I dont understand the reasons of this fault.

Can any one of you help me?

Comment: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException , i dont understand this exception

Comment: Could you start your jboss with debug output to provide some more information?

Comment: Could you attach **server.log** and **boot.log** ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting all files and folders in the tmp and work directories:

```
   C:/Users/aroua/jbdevstudioo/jboss-eap/jboss-as/server/default/tmp/
   C:/Users/aroua/jbdevstudioo/jboss-eap/jboss-as/server/default/work/
```

Comment: Delete all files and folders in those directories.

Comment: i used Jboss developer Studio and there is an option to clean project ant server i try to do the clean but the problem persist , and for what the reasons to delete the files int the tmp and work ??? sorry but i'm a beggening in used the server jboss

Comment: i found the problem the server couldnt find myclass javazoom (javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException) i used it to convert a file mp3 to file .wav , how can i solve this problem , i need to do this task ???

Comment: the console show me this error :Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javazoom/jl/decoder/JavaLayerException
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
 at org.jboss.seam.Component.hasAnnotation(Component.java:1158)
 at org.jboss.seam.Component.<init>(Component.java:218)
 at org.jboss.seam.Component.<init>(Component.java:205)
 at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.addComponent(Initialization.java:1186)

Comment: Edit your question and add the stack trace there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the Jar with the library available to jboss. Either include it in you war or stick it in the lib folder of jboss.

Comment: where can i find the library available to jboss of javazoom??